# ¿Cómo puedo multiplicar dos listas?

Tags: python, lista

Estoy trabajando en un programa en Phython para obtener el indice académico de la universidad para ello necesito multiplicar la calificación obtenida en una materia por los créditos de dicha materia. He creado dos listas: en una se insertan los créditos y en otra las calificaciones y necesito multiplicar cada elemento de una lista con su equivalente en la otra.

Por ejm. el primero de una lista por el primero de la segunda lista y así sucesivamente. He intentado resolverlo pero no me da el resultado esperado porque los números se multiplican como en una operación de polinomios.

```
>>> lista_creditos = [3,4,2,6]
>>> lista_calificaciones = [98, 80,86,78]
>>> 
>>> lista_multi = []
>>> 
>>> for x in lista_creditos:
    for y in lista_calificaciones:
        lista_multi.append(x*y)


>>> print lista_multi
[294, 240, 258, 234, 392, 320, 344, 312, 196, 160, 172, 156, 588, 480, 516, 468]
>>>
```

Comment: Bienvenido Alexander es bueno tenerte aquí, te sugiero leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida. También, aprovecha y realiza el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Alexander, lee el [tour] como mi compañero Jorgesys te sugiere. Tambien veo que publicaste una respuesta que era un agradecimiento hacia las respuestas... eso significa que has encontrado la solucion? COnsidera marcar como aceptada (el tick bajo la puntuacion)  la respuesta que consideres más apropiada, un saludo.

Answer (score 8):

Con tu código multiplicas cada elemento de la primera lista por cada uno de los elementos de la segunda al usar los dos `for` anidados. Debes usar solo un `for` u otras alternativas que brinda Python.

Tienes varias formas de hacerlo usando Python estándar, entre ellas (***ordenadas de mejor a peor en cuanto a tiempo de ejecución***):

- **Usar `operator.mul` junto a `map`:**

  ```
  import operator

  lista_creditos = [3,4,2,6]
  lista_calificaciones = [98, 80,86,78]

  lista_multi = list(map(operator.mul, lista_creditos, lista_calificaciones))
  ```
- **Ciclo `for` junto a `zip` (compresión de listas):**

  ```
  lista_creditos = [3,4,2,6]
  lista_calificaciones = [98, 80,86,78]

  lista_multi = [a*b for a,b in zip(lista_creditos, lista_calificaciones)]
  ```
- **Ciclo `for`  junto a `enumerate` (compresión de listas)**:

  ```
  lista_creditos = [3,4,2,6]
  lista_calificaciones = [98, 80,86,78]

  lista_multi = [lista_creditos[i] * lista_calificaciones[i]
                     for i in range(len(lista_creditos))]
  ```
- **Ciclo `for` junto a `range` y `len`(compresión de listas):**

  ```
  lista_creditos = [3,4,2,6]
  lista_calificaciones = [98, 80,86,78]

  lista_multi = [c * lista_calificaciones[i] for i, c in enumerate(lista_creditos)]
  ```
- **`map` junto a una función `lambda`**(no recomendable):

  ```
  lista_creditos = [3,4,2,6]
  lista_calificaciones = [98, 80,86,78]

  lista_multi = list(map(lambda x,y: x*y, lista_creditos, lista_calificaciones))
  ```

En todos los casos la salida será:

> [294, 320, 172, 468]

El uso de listas por compresión hace el código significativamente más eficiente al trabajar a nivel de C, no obstante puedes usar estructuras `for` normales junto a `append` si lo deseas, por ejemplo:

```
lista_multi = []

for a,b in zip(lista_creditos, lista_calificaciones):
    lista_multi.append(a*b)
```

o

```
lista_multi = []

for i in range(len(lista_creditos)):
    lista_multi.append(lista_creditos[i] * lista_calificaciones[i])
```

Si tengo que elegir creo que usar compresión de listas junto a `zip` es una opción bastante simple y eficiente para hacer lo que quieres.

> **Nota:** todas las opciones funcionan tanto en Python 2 como en Python 3. Si se usa Python 2 no es necesario el casting a `list` cuando se usa `map` ya que retorna una lista directamente.

Comment: porqué no recomiendas el uso del map/lambda ? por lo que suelo trabajar suele ser mas eficiente que un for, llamemosle el apply de R. Un saludo

Comment: @PeCaDe map/lambda es más eficiente que `for`  "normales" pero esto no siempre es cierto al compararlo con listas por compresión. Los dos primeros métodos son los mejores con diferencia, `map` + `lambda` para listas pequeñas puede ser mejor (solo superado por los dos anteriores y Numpy) pero con iterables relativamente grandes puede llegar a ser bastante ineficiente. Acabo de hacer algunos test para listas de 5000000 elementos y es 22 veces más lento que `operator.mul`. El principal problema es que con `lambda` se usan funciones Python puras y se produce una sobrecarga de llamadas importante.

Comment: Funciones como `operator.mul` o las listas por compresión tienen mucho código C compilado detrás (al igual que Numpy) por lo que son mucho más eficientes que usar funciones puras de Python. Siendo realistas la diferencia es inapreciable para listas relativamente pequeñas, se puede usar `map`+`lambda` si se desea sin problemas y, en algunos casos, son muy útiles dado que son mucho más flexibles. Esta diferencia también se observa al ordenar con `list.sort` o `sorted` y enfrentar `key = lambda x:  x[0]`  frente a `key = operator.itemgetter(0)` por ejemplo.

Comment: TOP! Gracias por la respuesta. Ha sido muy didactico. @FJSevilla

Answer (score 1):

También tienes esta solcución a modo de tutorial numpy:

- **Uso de `Multiply` mediante numpy:**(lo que buscabas)

  ```
  import numpy as np

  np.multiply(lista_creditos,lista_calificaciones)

  Out[1]: 
  array([294, 320, 172, 468])
  ```
- **Uso de `Multiply` mediante compresion de listas:**("lo que estabas haciendo")

  ```
  l = [np.multiply(i,lista_calificaciones) for i in lista_creditos]
  [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]

  Out[2]:
  [294, 240, 258, 234, 392, 320, 344, 312, 196, 160, 172, 156, 588, 480, 516, 468]
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Considerando que tenes la misma cantidad de elementes, solo debes recorrer uno de ellos y deacuerdo al valor de indice hacer la multiplicacion

```js
lista_creditos = [3,4,2,6]
lista_calificaciones = [98, 80,86,78]
 
lista_multi = []
i = 0 
for x in lista_creditos:
 cr = lista_creditos[i]
 ca = lista_calificaciones[i]
 print cr, ca, cr * ca
 lista_multi.append(cr*ca)
 i = i + 1


print lista_multi
```

Otra forma de recorrer los elementos:

```
nro = len(lista_creditos)
for i in range(nro):
    cr = lista_creditos[i]
    ca = lista_calificaciones[i]
    print cr, ca, cr * ca
```

Answer (score 0):

Con numpy puedes trabajar facilmente con listas y todas sus operaciones de forma sencilla.

```
import numpy as np
np_creditos = np.array([3,4,2,6])
np_calificaciones = np.array([98, 80,86,78])

np_multiplicacion = np_creditos * np_calificaciones
print (np_multiplicacion)
>>> [294 320 172 468]
```

Recuerda que numpy solo acepta un tipo de datos para cada lista , si necesitas tener varios tipos de datos `["hola", 4,6]` deberas usar **pandas** u otra librería.

Answer (score 0):

#### Muliplicar dos listas en Python

Una manera diferente de desarrollarlo. Si bien el recorrido para **multiplicar listas** no varia demasiado a las respuestas anteriores, lo planteo con una **clase** donde además de **guardar las listas** de cada materia y multiplicar se podrían desarrollar mas funciones para hacer otro tipo de consultas.

##### Listas y clase

```
# Las listas de créditos asignados y calificaciones de la materia

lista_creditos = [3,4,2,6]
lista_calificaciones = [98,80,86,78]


class IndiceAcademicoMateria:
    def __init__(self, creditos, calificaciones):
        self.creditos = creditos
        self.calificaciones = calificaciones
        self.resultados = [] # Mantiene resultados

    def multiplicar(self):
        self.resultados = [] # vacia lista
        if len(self.creditos) == len(self.calificaciones): # compara largo
            for i in range(len(self.creditos)):
                self.resultados.append(self.calificaciones[i] * self.creditos[i])
            return self.resultados
        else:
            raise Exception("Las listas deben tener el mismo numero de elementos")

    def resultadosMateria(self):
        return self.resultados # muestra resultados

    def promedio(self):
        suma = 0
        for i in range(len(self.resultados)):
            suma += self.resultados[i]
        return suma / len(self.resultados)


# Instanciamos la clase
matematica = IndiceAcademicoMateria(lista_creditos, lista_calificaciones)
```

Ahora creada la instancia de `class IndiceAcademicoMateria` recibe por parámetros las dos listas de igual tamaño.

##### Multiplicando listas

Dentro de la función `def multiplicar(self)` la primera linea comienza vaciando la lista `self.resultados = []` para los casos donde existan valores anteriores. Siguiente paso verificara que las listas tengan el mismo largo `if len(self.creditos) == len(self.calificaciones)`. Si las listas no tienen el mismo largo lanzara un `raise Exception("Las listas deben tener el mismo numero de elementos")`.

La función `def resultadosMateria(self)` nos devuelve la lista de resultados actuales, sin volver a realizar la multiplicación.

`def promedio(self)` no devolverá el promedio sobre los valores en variable de los resultados calculados en la ultima multiplicación realizada.

Pedimos información al objeto `matematica` sobre las dos listas.

```
print("Multiplicar listas: ", matematica.multiplicar())
print("Promedio de multiplicación: ", matematica.promedio())
print("Resultado archivado: ", matematica.resultadosMateria())
```

Se puede visualizar las diferentes devoluciones:

```
Multiplicar listas:  [294, 320, 172, 468]
Promedio de multiplicación:  313.5
Resultado archivado:  [294, 320, 172, 468]
```

Aclaración: Si se carga una nueva lista al objeto `matematica` con nuevos valores, será necesario volver a calcular la multiplicación con `matematica.multiplicar()` para que los valores de `self.resultados = []` se actualicen, sino seguirán cargados en lista los anteriores.